# Can we say A is under possession of B?

Tags: grammar

I am translating a legal text. I want to say the land mentioned earlier in the text belongs to Mr. X. I want to use *possession* for ownership here. Can I write?

> One quarter of the whole property mentioned earlier is under possession of Mr. X.

Comment: I would say "In the possession of Mr. X."

Comment: Note that lawyers speak a different dialect of English. In the common-law tradition *possession* is a "term of art"--a technical term--and does not mean quite the same thing as *ownership*. I'm not a lawyer, but my impression is that you may be in possession of something without "owning" it--having *title* in it--and you have the legal right to defend that possession against anybody except the person who has title in it.

Comment: There is always the [Legal Dictionary](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/possession) over at the free dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to use "in [possession](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/possession) of".

In short, "in" is the preposition used with "possession".

[Results for "under" were conclusive](https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=cr&ei=AphhVeKoLe7e7AbA0oGIBg#q=%22under+possession+of%22) (TL;DR - there weren't any).